# How to fix "Position Unavailable" error with html5 geolocation in android webview?

Tags: javascript, java, php, html

I'm building an app in android webview while loading html content from an external web server. The html content contains javascript code that uses geolocation to get user current position. The codes works fine in Chrome and Firefox but provides an error in android webview app. What should I do?

I'm targeting android with API 20 or higher and I have tried to include extra permission in android manifest file but nothing worked.

**Here HTML code file with Javascript code in an external server:**

```js
//get location
//var a = document.getElementById("demo");
var b = document.getElementById("lat");
var c = document.getElementById("long");
var d = document.getElementById("showDiv");


  var apiGeolocationSuccess = function(position) {

        b.style.display="block";  
        c.style.display="block";
        b.value = position.coords.latitude;
        c.value = position.coords.longitude;


    alert("API geolocation success!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);
};

var tryAPIGeolocation = function() {
    jQuery.post( "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyDCa1LUe1vOczX1hO_iGYgyo8p_jYuGOPU", function(success) {
        apiGeolocationSuccess({coords: {latitude: success.location.lat, longitude: success.location.lng}});
  })
  .fail(function(err) {
    alert("API Geolocation error! \n\n"+err);
  });
};

var browserGeolocationSuccess = function(position) {
  b.value = position.coords.latitude;
  c.value = position.coords.longitude;
  d.style.display = "block"; 

    alert("Browser geolocation success!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);
};

var browserGeolocationFail = function(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nTimeout.");
      break;
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      if(error.message.indexOf("Only secure origins are allowed") == 0) {
        tryAPIGeolocation();
      }
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nPosition unavailable.");
      break;
  }
};

var tryGeolocation = function() {

  b.style.display="block";  
  c.style.display="block";
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        browserGeolocationSuccess,
      browserGeolocationFail,
      {maximumAge: 50000, timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
  }
};

tryGeolocation();
```

**Android Manifest file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.erosaapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java.**

```java
/***  ------- */
package com.example.erosaapp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /*
      WebViewClient subclass loads all hyperlinks in the existing WebView
     */
    public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * WebChromeClient subclass handles UI-related calls
     * Note: think chrome as in decoration, not the Chrome browser
     */
    public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                                                       GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
            // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    }

    WebView myWebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String myurl = "https://erosa2019.000webhostapp.com";
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

        // Brower niceties -- pinch / zoom, follow links in place
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(20);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());

        // Below required for geolocation
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());

        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());

        myWebView.loadUrl(myurl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

I expect to get prompt asking for permission to have latitude and longtude, but gives "Browser geolocation error!  position unavailable"

Comment: Did you find a solution for this error?